# Python 3 base class type annotation only allow the current subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Let's say I've got three classes, one parent class, and two subclasses:

```
class BaseModel:
    def merge(self, other):
        return self + other

class ChildA(BaseModel):
    pass

class ChildB(BaseModel):
    pass
```

The parent class has a method that takes another instance of the current class and returns a new instance of the current class (out of scope for this question).

How do I annotate `BaseModel.merge` to restrict it to only the current subclass?

I can do something like this:

```
def merge(self, other: BaseModel) -> BaseModel:
    return self + other
```

But this still allows me to pass an instance of `ChildB` into `ChildA`, since both inherit from `BaseModel`. I only want `ChildA` to be allowed in `ChildA`, and `ChildB` to be allowed for `ChildB`. How can I do that without reimplementing `merge` on each subclass?

Comment: Consider the caller of such objects: `def foo(m: BaseModel): m.merge(ChildB())`. If `BaseModel` defines the method, any object that `isinstance(m, BaseModel)` (i.e. it and all its children) should behave the same and accept any instance of `BaseModel`. You're breaking the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Fair enough. It would be nice, given that the logic within the method is the same, to be able to do that. But maybe I can just wrap that logic in a method on the child class with the appropriate type annotation.

Comment: It's only a violation of the LSP if you claim `merge` can accept arbitrary instances of `BaseModel`, rather than instances of the *same* exact type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotate *both* arguments with a type variable, to enforce that both arguments must be of the same type.

```
from typing import TypeVar

B = TypeVar('B', bound='BaseModel')

class BaseModel:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self: B, other: B) -> B:
        return type(self)(self.x + other.x)

    def merge(self: B, other: B) -> B:
        return self + other

class ChildA(BaseModel):
    pass

class ChildB(BaseModel):
    pass


print(ChildA(3).merge(ChildA(4)).x)  # Valid; both arguments are ChildA      
print(ChildA(3).merge(ChildB(4)).x)  # Invalid; one ChildA and one ChildB
```

Comment: This seems to be the blessed way of doing this per [this issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/58)